# SQL join returns NULL even if result is not null

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to get info from 3 different tables using 2 different identifiers. But instead of returning clear results it returns me data with `NULL`'s instead of result. And the weirdest part is that 50% of all results are good and other 50% are missing that one field.

```
SELECT inventory.exterior, 
       inventory.steamid, 
       inventory.icon, 
       inventory.id, 
       inventory.name, 
       inventory.steam_item_id, 
       items_prices.price, 
       bots.id AS botID 
FROM   inventory 
       LEFT JOIN items_prices 
              ON items_prices.id = inventory.steamanalyst_id 
       LEFT JOIN bots 
              ON bots.steamid = inventory.steamid 
WHERE  inventory.steamid IN ( 123, 123, 123, 123, 
                              123 ... , 123 ) 
ORDER  BY items_prices.price DESC 
LIMIT  100 offset 0
```

so this returns me this:
and there instead of `NULL`s should be numbers like 1, 3, 7, 9 etc.

[image]

and this is structure of database tables.
`inventory` [image]

everything is fine with syntax, there are no errors in spelling on tables names, rows etc. It's just don't want to collect all data and returns nulls instead of data

Comment: Do you know how `LEFT JOIN` works?  If a given record on the left side of the join does not match anything on the right side of the join, the right table's column will still appear, but the values will all be `NULL`.  I'm not sure that anything is wrong here.

Comment: Wrong Joins?  Do you mean to be using inner joins instead of left?  LEFT will include all records from Inventory and only those that match from items_Prices and then again only those that match the previous and bots.  INNER Join will ensure records exist in all tables.

Comment: Show some sample data and table structure

Comment: some data from `inventory` table are unmatched in the joined `bots`  table. Code is not wrong.

Comment: I've tried with `INNER JOIN` as well but then results just dissapears. For example on the left of first screenshot there are `steamid` which matches row in `bots` table and should return good `id` as `botID` but it returns null.

Comment: Either you `INNER JOIN` and the "results" disappear, or you `LEFT JOIN` and then possibly `COALESCE` the `NULL` values to something else.  Besides this, if you data isn't there, then your query may have a problem with the logic.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but if I check for example first row and type `SELECT id AS botID FROM bots WHERE steamid = 76561198......` it returns me `3` not `NULL`

Comment: Most likely this record is being filtered off by one of the `LEFT JOIN`s you have in there.  Please review the basics of joining in SQL.

Comment: I hope that data isn't sensitive. The half-hearted attempt at masking is a bit easy to read through. That first row only has two fully obscured characters... Would suggest blacking it out completely next time.

Answer (score 0):

The `NULL` are because of the `LEFT JOIN`.  Use `INNER JOIN` if you don't want to see them:

```
SELECT i.exterior, i.steamid, i.icon, i.id, i.name, i.steam_item_id, 
       ip.price, b.id AS botID 
FROM inventory i JOIN
     items_prices ip 
     ON ip.id = i.steamanalyst_id JOIN
     bots b 
     ON b.steamid = i.steamid 
WHERE i.steamid IN ( 123, 123, 123, 123, 
                      123 ... , 123 ) 
ORDER BY ip.price DESC 
LIMIT 100 OFSET 0;
```

If you want all records, even if there is no match in the `bots` table, then just use a `LEFT JOIN` for `bots`.